# High Frequency Ferrites for Transformers

Tags: power-supply, rf, ferrite

There are many Ferrite material grades Available.The optimum frequencies start around 20KHz and extend well into the MHz range.There are also many core sizes to go from watts to Kw .Planar cores are now readily available .Planar transformers are now more normal where 20 years ago they were exotic.WHY don't they make large cores like say E64 in high frequency ferrite grades like 3F45  or      3F5 for say 2 MHz?  Is there some technical reason maybe to do with metallurgy why they don't OR is it some market thing because most people don't do Kw at MHz ?

Comment: If nobody here can answer this question, e-mail [Elna Magnetics](http://www.elnamagnetics.com/).

Comment: Its early days yet !I have been trying to find out every year for 11 years now .Its frustrating that we in CHCH NZ have been stuck with 3F4 for 12 years.I and my boss then agreed that better ferrites would arrive,but in our big planars the 3f5 isnot available.

Comment: It is off-topic, but what is CHCH? Christchurch? If there is no techinical barrier, I would think they would make it for you if you have any decent volume at all.

Comment: The optimum frequencies start at DC for ALL ferrites and not 20 kHz.

Comment: @ Andy aka .I assume that below say 20KHz transformers tend to run laminations or powdered iron .